# How to make a push notification for a pass

Tags: ios6, push-notification, passbook

I made a pass web service already. Next, I need to make a push notification when my pass is updated. From Updating a pass of passkit programming guide, it is not in detail. Can you explain this in detail ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The requirements and protocol for push notifications is documented in the [Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9).

There are a few special considerations for Passbook:

1. All Pass push requests must be sent to the production APNS server (gateway.push.apple.com on port 2195)
2. You must use your Pass Type ID certificate and key to authenticate with the APNS server (do not use App APNS certificates)
3. There is no need to handle device registrations, you simply use the `pushToken` that your web service received when the device registered the pass
4. The payload should be an empty - E.g. `{"aps":""}`
5. `alert`, `badge`, `sound` and custom property keys are all ignored - the push's only purpose is to notify Passbook that your web service has a fresh pass.  The notification text will be determined by the `changeMessage` key in pass.json and the differences between the old and the new .pkpass bundles
6. The`changeMessage` string should contain `%@` if you wish for the content of the `value` key to be displayed. Change messages may have static text in addition to the `%@` variable, such as this: `"changeMessage":"New updates: %@"`. If no `%@` is provided, a generic message with the kind of pass is displayed: `"Store card changed"`.
7. As of iOS9, if you modify more than one field at a time, only one generic message will be displayed on the lock screen.
8. You still need to regularly query the feedback service and purge expired/invalid pushTokens from your database

Note that push updates can be implemented independently of your web service.  Apple provide some sample objective-c code in [Listing 5-1 here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html).

Comment: Do I use only php for sending push notification to a pass in device ? not objective-c ?

Comment: Do I configure only web service ?

Comment: Use whatever you are more comfortable with (could also be Java, Ruby, Pearl, Python or any other language).  The sending of the push notification can be completely independent of your web service.  It all depends how you will be triggering pushes in the future.

Comment: my web service works already, but not yet for push notification. I never do a push notification for app before ! Beside the special points you said above, is there any notification for me as a starter for APNS ?

Comment: For passbook, pushes are not very complicated.  Build the push payload, open a socket using your certificate, send the payload then close the socket.  The device will receive the push a few seconds later then it will call your web service with a get serials request.

Comment: So I need to search for how to build push payload, to open a socket using certificate of pass, to send payload and these are all that I have to do ?

Comment: You may also need to export your certificate from your keychain and prepare it to open the socket.  Everything you need, including sample code is in the link at the end of the answer.

Comment: The code in listing 5.1 is objective-c which I though you were more familiar with.  You could use that code to create a simple command line app that takes the public key filename, private key filename and pushToken,  as parameters.

Comment: what kind of certificate that I need to export ? (as .pem or .p12 and it is from pass certificate ?)

Comment: Do you think I can do push notification for a pass only 1 day ?

Comment: I have only tomorrow to finish this !

Comment: It all depends on what you define as 'finish' because what you have so far still needs to be transferred to a live web server and you may need to automate logic to automatically update and upload new passes if it is going to be used commercially.  But if you just need a proof of concept to send a single push message then it should only take a couple of hours using a language that you are competent in.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](https://www.billguard.com/blog/2012/10/coding-passbook-lessons-learned/) to export the cert and how to send the push in Java

Comment: yes, first I need only a sigle push that can update a pass automatically without the notice of user ! can you give me some clues on that ?

Comment: Thank you ! I hope to understand a lot from it !

Comment: how to use changeMessage ? and query the feedback service ?

Comment: You should post a separate question for `changeMessage` and the feedback service.

Comment: +1 for recognizing the push gateway is production instead of sandbox!

Comment: Any one solve this problem?. Push notification received but passbook not updated automatically. Pull to refresh is working

Comment: @PassKit please, are you sure, I should use Pass Type ID certifikate and key? It is constantly refusing my key. If I use App APNS certifikate, return from APNS is "delivered", but it is not in fact delivered (of course).

Comment: @Autista_z Yes absolutely sure - it is very clearly stated in the documentation.  I would recommend double checking your key and the format.

Comment: @PassKit oh, im stupid. I used wrong pem file (not created from p12, so no signed from Apple). My mistake. thanks