# Push notification doesn't work for Passbook from C#

Tags: c#, passbook

I am trying to achieve Apple Push notification for Passbook from C#. I am not getting any error or exception but the notification is not received on device.

Following are steps already taken
- I am trying it with production pass p12 certificate which I am using for Pass signing
- I am having my tcp port 2196 open as required by APNS
- I am sending empty Json payload and push token (which I am receiving from passbook when user adds pass to passbook and our service is invoked)

When I am trying to read response from the SSLstream I am getting it as \b\a\0\0\0\0

Any help will be great help. Thanks!

Comment: First, ensure you're using the right endpoint APNS endpoint. Second, are you seeing anything in the iPhone logs of the device you're pushing to?

Comment: Is your webServiceURL receiving a request for serials and is it responding appropriately? Is this request followed by a second request to receive the updated .pkpass bundle? Is the updated .pkpass bundle different to the original bundle? Is a changeMessage set for the value that has changed, and does this message contain %@?  You are developing in C# and so may not have access to Xcode for debugging - if so and if your webServiceURL is a public URL, if you can post a link to the .pkpass bundle, we can help diagnose for you.

Comment: @PassKit  - I have all web services in place so when I am trying pull to update my getpass service is invoked and pass is updated, I can see that through device logs. Both the bundles are same as there is no change in pass content, my requirement is I need to show a push notification to user with some message in notification after 7 days of pass installation. I dont have changemessage field in pass.json. Do I need to add changeMessage? Wont it work without it?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness - I am pointing to gateway.push.apple.com and port 2195. Mostly nothing is coming through still I will confirm it again and update here.

Answer (score 0):

You DO need a `changeMessage` if you want anything to show on the lockscreen, but you could also consider a [`relevantDate` alert](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53) if it is always after 7 days.  The following answer details all of the mandatory requirements to invoke a lock screen message from a push to a pass. [How to make a push notification for a pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass/).

Specifically note point 5:

> `alert`, `badge`, `sound` and `custom` property keys are all ignored - the
>   push's only purpose is to notify Passbook that your web service has a
>   fresh pass. The notification text will be determined by the
>   `changeMessage` key in pass.json and the differences between the old and
>   the new .pkpass bundles

Comment: I have added required changeMessage key in the pass.json file. Now when I try to run the code, after some period of time I am getting a Get request with passesupdatedsince tag in the xcode console (not consistent). Not sure whether its coming because of the code or passbook itself invokes it after some specific duration.

Comment: That call can only be triggered by the push.