# Will Apple's APNS server let me send random Push Notifications to my Pass users?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, passbook

If i have a pass generated and distributed over a bunch of PassBook users' devices, and i want to send a push notification outside of a pass update, would i be able to do so?

The documentation isn't clear. Has anyone had any experience with this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW59 I understand i'll have all the pushTokens from the devices usin fmy pass, so could i use them to send out notifications?

Once i build the web service that pushes the updated passes, can i use that service to send notifications without pass update? Just random communication with users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the past content and have a `changeMessage` key set for the updated field(s) if you want anything to show on the lockscreen.

The following answer details all of the mandatory requirements to invoke a lock screen message from a push to a pass. [How to make a push notification for a pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass/).

Specifically note point 5:

> `alert`, `badge`, `sound` and `custom` property keys are all ignored - the
>   push's only purpose is to notify Passbook that your web service has a
>   fresh pass. The notification text will be determined by the
>   `changeMessage` key in pass.json and the differences between the old and
>   the new .pkpass bundles

Comment: thanks PassKit :) Does this mean i can enter any copy i like in the changeMessage key? and does this mean that the changeMessage only appears in the lock screen as a notification? or does it appear in all the usual places that a push notification appears? Thanks again for your response, Vauneen

Comment: Appears in all of the usual places - however, the change message just contain the %@ placeholder, which will be replaced with the value of the new field.  Otherwise you will just see a generic message of "Pass Changed"