# Push Notification for a pass added to the default Wallet Application

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, passbook

I've built a Ruby on Rails application to create passes and interact with Apple to manage pass registration and updates. For the most part, I followed this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/whats-in-your-wallet-handling-ios-passbook-with-ruby/

I've watched these apple videos about apple passbook (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/301/) and have setup my app's API according to the passkit documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html).

Right now, I'm able to create passes in my RoR application and add them to my iphone (either via email or download link). However, after updating the pass and triggering the push notification to APNS I don't get the push notification in my device. My device is correctly registered with my application when I add it for the first time. And the pass gets updated as expected if I go to the back of the pass and refresh it.

The only problem I'm having is delivering those push notifications to the apple wallet app. I don't know if I'm missing anything, I've read lots of posts that mention enabling push notifications for your own IOS app but I don't really need an IOS app; if my passes are added to the apple's default wallet app I just want to push notifications to it.

My device's push token is generated correctly, I've tried with both the production and sandbox APNS endpoints and certificates using the grocer gem and I've even tried the server reference that comes with those apple videos, I don't get any errors but I don't get any notifications either. I've confirmed that my iphone has notifications enabled for the wallet app.

I'd appreciate if anybody can lead me to the right track to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried with both the production and sandbox APNS endpoints and
>   certificates using the grocer gem

Your issue is you are using the wrong certificate.

Use your PassTypeID certificate to connect to the APNS production endpoint.

See [How to make a push notification for a pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had read that and tried using the Pass Type ID cert but I get: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError (Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error). Does this mean I did something wrong while generating the certifcate? I downloaded the .cert file and then exported the pem file from key chain.

Comment: Just to make sure, this is the same cert I use to sign the passes right?

Comment: Correct - same certificate.  Export the same way you do for the APNS certs.

Comment: Also do a modulus check to make sure your key and cert match

Comment: I see what the error was. The certificates I had didn't have a private key associated (in keychain I couldn't see the arrow to expand on the nested items) so the resulting .pem file didn't have the key information. I regenerated the cert and it worked just fine. Well, I don't see the actual push notification but the passes now get updated automatically and I can now see the requests the device makes to update the pass so I guess I'm good now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help - please mark the answer as accepted so others are aware.