# Push notification is not being recieved on iphone. It is delivered from server aparently. It may be implementation error

Tags: php, ios, laravel, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I am trying to send push notification to apple's Passbook application on updation of a coupon, in order to update it in PassBook application on device. 
According to apple's passbook documentation I am sending an empty push notification but it is not being received on device. I have tried to send with some text in the push notification but results are same.
I am using this PHP [library](https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP) to send push notification. 
Here is my implementation which is being called on coupon update action;

```
// Adjust to your timezone
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
        // Report all PHP errors
        error_reporting(-1);
        //Instantiate a new ApnsPHP_Push object
        $push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
            ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION,
            base_path().'/config/ios-push-notification-certificates/production/ProductionCertificate.pem'
        );
        // Set the Provider Certificate passphrase
        $push->setProviderCertificatePassphrase('mypassphrase');
        // Set the Root Certificate Autority to verify the Apple remote peer
        $push->setRootCertificationAuthority(base_path().'/config/ios-push-notification-certificates/entrust_root_certificate.pem');
        // Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
        $push->connect();
        // Instantiate a new Message with a single recipient
        $message = new ApnsPHP_Message('b2ae8b68fff1fbbe957b8b8f703744794d89f09d45f69b2d847a26c3b064e268');
        // Set a custom identifier. To get back this identifier use the getCustomIdentifier() method
        // over a ApnsPHP_Message object retrieved with the getErrors() message.
        $message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-3");
        // Set badge icon to "3"
        $message->setBadge(3);
        // Set a simple welcome text
        $message->setText('');
        // Play the default sound
        $message->setSound();
        // Set a custom property
        $message->setCustomProperty('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));
        // Set another custom property
        $message->setCustomProperty('acme3', array('bing', 'bong'));
        // Set the expiry value to 30 seconds
        $message->setExpiry(30);
        // Add the message to the message queue
        $push->add($message);
        // Send all messages in the message queue
        $push->send();
        // Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Service
        $push->disconnect();

        // Examine the error message container
        $aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
        if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
            print_r($aErrorQueue);
        }
```

And here is the output printed by the library which show message has been sent. It is not `print_r($aErrorQueue);` output. 
[image]
I didn't get why I am unable to update the pass automatically or receive the push notification. It is quite new to me this push notification service. Please guide me if I can debug any thing or try something else. My endpoints for apple server are working fine I can install and update the pass manually from passbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a push notification for a pass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass)

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are using the wrong certificate.  Also the payload should be empty, badges and content are ignored. The message content is triggered by differences between the old and new passes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass.

Comment: @PassKit I am using production certificate generated for APNS service. Is it wrong? Should I user the same certificate which I used to sign the pass when creating? And `$message->setText('');` this doesn't mean that the payload is empty?

Comment: I have double checked my data on server. I cleared all registered devices and tried again to install the new pass on passbook and device is successfully registered to my server. I can update pass from within the passbook application by manually using pull to refresh and it gives proper notification that {some value} has changed and I get updated pass in passbook.

Comment: The documentation and my other post are very clear. Connect with Pass Type ID certificate and send an empty payload.