# issue in Apple Passwallete integration with php

Tags: php, passbook, passkit

I have generated PASS with my code and also get device id, pushtoken in response from device.

here is code by which I am store all device and Pass information in database.

```
   $params = array(
                    "get"=>$_GET,
                    "request"=>$_REQUEST,
                    "post"=>$_POST,
                    "server"=>$_SERVER
                );
$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
$myfile = file_put_contents('callback.txt', json_encode($params).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$myfile = file_put_contents('log.txt', $content.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$header = json_encode(getallheaders());
$myfile = file_put_contents('header.txt', $header.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);



/*
 * store registered device data
 * */

$str = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
$str = stripslashes($str);


$url_slot = parse_url($str);
$urlArray = explode('/',$url_slot['path']);
$passid = $urlArray['11']; // serial no
$deviceId = $urlArray['8'];
$passtype = $urlArray['10'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=''', 'yyyy', 'zzzz');


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO devices_passes (device_id, pass_id, pass_type, created, modified) VALUES
(:device_id,:pass_id,:pass_type,:created,:modified)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':device_id', $device_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass_id', $pass_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass_type', $pass_type);
    $stmt->bindParam(':created', date('d-m-y'));
    $stmt->bindParam(':modified', date('d-m-y'));

    $device_id = $deviceId;
    $pass_id = $passid;
    $pass_type = $passtype;

    $stmt->execute();
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}



try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yyyy', 'uuuuu', 'yyyyyy');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO devices (push_token) VALUES
(:push_token)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':push_token', $push_token);
    $push_token = $content['pushToken'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

But when I send push notification to device , it will not reflect anything in device.
here is code of sending push notification to device.

```
<?php
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apple_push_notification_production.pem';
$push_token = 'my token';
$passIdentify = 'pass.yyyyy.xxxx';

$payload = '{}';
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $push_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload . pack('n', strlen($passIdentify)) . $passIdentify;

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

fwrite($apns, $msg);

@socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);

?>
```

Can you please help me when I am going wrong ??

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass) for a checklist.  You need to make sure that you have the change message set, and that the new pass content is different to the old pass content.

Comment: where can I add changeMessage parameter ? sending notification ??

Comment: I got your point
but if I generate updated .pkpass file how device get know about that update ?

Comment: You add it in the new pass' `pass.json`

Comment: yes but how device get automatic update. right now first time when I send link to device by mail and when hit the link pass will be generated and ask to add in wallet or  not . so how can I send updated pass ?

Comment: It's all in the documentation - you need to implement the other parts of the web service for the device to be able to pull the latest version from your server.  Step one would be having the pass update when you pull down on the back of the pass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142882/discussion-between-kruti-aparnathi-and-passkit).

Comment: device is not sending me this request GET request to webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag

Comment: It will send a request to get serials first

Comment: yes I have send serials  $curl_post_data = "{ lastUpdate: $lastupdate, serialNumbers: ['738489']}";  on this url $service_url = 'http://www.webclueslab.com/qa/skywire/passAPI-ios/examples/callback.php/v1/devices/9e17fb1bf487de153e9e17bf7ae5fafb/registrations/pass.webclues.testSkywire/738489';

Comment: I am not getting where I am wrong...

Comment: Have you implemented all the endpoints for he web service, including the logging endpoint.  Also try watching the iPhone logs in the console as you send the push.

Comment: what is logging endpoint do u mean authentication token verification?

Comment: The logging endpoint is part of the PassKit web service you need to provide yourself, see the [PassKit Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988-CH0-SW7) for more information.

Comment: I was referring this document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html  generating PAS first then device respond me with registration. I have stored device id and push token in my database and then I was trying to send notification code using above code , so now device should call https:////devices/
  /registrations/?passesUpdatedSince= webservice so I can provide updated pass identifier. but my webservice is not getting passesUpdatedSince. what is going wrong here please help

Comment: You won't see that parameter on the first request.  Only on subsequent requests after you have delivered a pass including a last updated header

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988 you should be using this document.

Comment: do you have final code? is it working now?