# Apple Wallet Push Notification sending issue from PHP

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, wallet, passkit

i checked most of the posts try to do everything, but still not able to receive push notification on my cell phone.

problem is there no error coming showing `Message successfully delivered string(141)'. On phone im not receiving anything. could you please please see code & point area where i have to see error.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../mobilewallet/config.php';
$errstrn = "";

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $push_cert_passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $push_cert_uri_pem);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
stream_set_blocking ($fp, 0); 


if (!$fp) {
    //ERROR
    echo "Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): $err $errstrn";
} else {

    // Create the payload body

    $body['aps'] = array(
      'alert' => "Hello World",
      'sound' => 'default',
      'link_url' => "http://www.abc.en",
    );

    //$payload = json_encode($body);
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    //Enhanced Notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $push_device_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    //SEND PUSH
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg); 
    //We can check if an error has been returned while we are sending, but we also need to check once more after we are done sending in case there was a delay with error response.
    checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
    checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
    usleep(500000); //Pause for half a second. Note I tested this with up to a 5 minute pause, and the error message was still available to be retrieved
    checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);

    if (!$result)
      echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else {
      echo 'Message successfully delivered ' . PHP_EOL;
      var_dump('message ' .$msg .'result   {' .$result .'}');
    }

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
}


function checkAppleErrorResponse($fp) {

   //byte1=always 8, byte2=StatusCode, bytes3,4,5,6=identifier(rowID). Should return nothing if OK.
   $apple_error_response = fread($fp, 6);
   //NOTE: Make sure you set stream_set_blocking($fp, 0) or else fread will pause your script and wait forever when there is no response to be sent.
   if ($apple_error_response) {
        //unpack the error response (first byte 'command" should always be 8)
        $error_response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $apple_error_response);

        if ($error_response['status_code'] == '0') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '0-No errors encountered';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '1') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '1-Processing error';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '2') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '2-Missing device token';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '3') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '3-Missing topic';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '4') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '4-Missing payload';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '5') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '5-Invalid token size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '6') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '6-Invalid topic size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '7') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '7-Invalid payload size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '8') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '8-Invalid token';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '255') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '255-None (unknown)';
        } else {
            $error_response['status_code'] = $error_response['status_code'] . '-Not listed';
        }

        echo '<br><b>+ + + + + + ERROR</b> Response Command:<b>' . $error_response['command'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Identifier:<b>' . $error_response['identifier'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status:<b>' . $error_response['status_code'] . '</b><br>';
        echo 'Identifier is the rowID (index) in the database that caused the problem, and Apple will disconnect you from server. To continue sending Push Notifications, just start at the next rowID after this Identifier.<br>';

        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Without digging too much into your code, you should be aware that the socket based push service you are connected to has been deprecated and replaced by a new http2 service. If you are developing a new service, you may be better off implementing the http2 than spending time debugging this code.

Comment: Second thing to note is that the payload is ignored in the case of passes.  Any alert will be as a result of a change in the pass.json and will only show if a `changeMessage` is set against the field that has changed.  This is explained quite extensively in both the documentation and other answers, such as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass

Comment: Thanks so much for ur quick reply.. for http2 u have any example links it will be great help.  And when we send empty payload does it show on wallet card any alert ?

Comment: @PassKit  hi can you please any resource for how to generate certificate for PHP passkit project. i found so many maybe resource and i fallowed the steps even but no result. maybe  im missing something thats why im not able to push message ?

Comment: If you are looking for copy/paste code, I cannot help you.  Better you study the documentation and write your own code that you understand.

Comment: im not looking  copy/paste  @all im asking link/url where i can read i already accomplished so much just only stuck send push new changes and push notification im reading everywhere im just asking if please you can give me good documentation link which can help me in my issue. it will be great help.  thank you soooo much

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wallet

Comment: I already read so maytime I don't know what I'm missing why my push message not going :(. Maybe this technology is new for me that's why taking. Thank you .

Comment: should i send only changed data in get request ? "changeMessage" : "Boarding time changed to %@.".  should i deliver full new.pkpass?

Comment: You need a full, signed .pkpass each time.  Also make sure the content-type and last-modified headers are correctly set.

Comment: I'm keeping this above line in my db field and sending only this. So I'm assuming it will compare my old Json file find this key and change it .. right ?

Comment: @PassKit sir please help me im very near ... please