# How to send push notification from wallet device push token?

Tags: ios, go, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, wallet

I'm working on designing and developing [Apple wallet passes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/index.html). All steps are done and I got push token for the device at Registering device step.

My question: can I use this push token to send like "alert" push notifications to devices? if yes, how?

My golang sample I tried but it is not working:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
    "github.com/sideshow/apns2"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    pushToken := "device-pushToken"
    passTypeIdentifier := "my-passTypeIdentifier"

    var cert tls.Certificate
    //Initialize certificate here 
    
    notification := &apns2.Notification{}
    notification.PushType = apns2.PushTypeAlert
    notification.DeviceToken = pushToken
    notification.Topic = passTypeIdentifier
    notification.Priority = 10
    notification.Expiration = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 4)
    notification.Payload = []byte(`{"aps": {
                                    "alert": {
                                      "title": "Your food is done.",
                                      "body": "Be careful, it's really hot!"
                                    }
                                  }}`)

    client := apns2.NewClient(cert).Production()
    res, err := client.Push(notification)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Msg(err.Error())
    }
    log.Info().Int("status: ", res.StatusCode).Msg("push token apple status.")  
    // {"level":"info","status: ":200,"time":"2021-11-27T17:20:50+03:00","message":"push token apple status."}
    // but is not showed in the device
}
```

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without the ios side of things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a push notification for a pass].  It refers to the legacy APNS service, but the content of the payload and the need for a changeMessage in pass.json remain the same. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass)

Comment: @PassKit awesome ! that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @myusuf3 no the answer already in the link @ passkit has provided. It is about using changeMessage for the field inside the pass